# Macro with NSLocalizedString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macros

```
#define A @"someString"
#define B NSLocalizedString(@"someLocalizableString",nil) A
```

I'm trying to concatenate a localizable string in a "#define" but it's not work. It's that possible to do that in a Macro please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define A @"someString"
#define B [NSLocalizedString(@"someLocalizableString",nil) stringByAppendingString:A]
```

the result is `somelocalizableStringsomeString`